# OpenGL ES2.0 Lighting in the vertex shader or fragment shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, lighting

I have seen many different tutorials on lighting in OpenGL ES2.0.

Some use the vertex shader to do all the lighting and transforms and then just pass the final colour through the fragment shader.

Others pass the position and other variables from the vertex shader and then do all the lighting in the fragment shader.

From my experience i always thought lighting should be done in the fragment shader. Can anyone tell my why do one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditional, fixed-pipeline OpenGL did lighting at the vertices and merely interpolated per fragment. So it tended to show visible seaming along edges:

[image]

That was considered an acceptable compromise however, because lighting was *too* expensive to do per-pixel. Hardware is better now but lighting is still *more* expensive to do per pixel. So I guess there's a potential argument there. Also I guess if you were trying to emulate the old fixed pipeline you might deliberately do lighting inaccurately.

However I'm struggling to think of any particularly sophisticated algorithm that would be amenable. Is it possible that the examples you've seen are just doing things like figuring out the tangent and cotangent vectors per vertex, or some other similar expensive step, then interpolating those per pixel and doing the absolute final calculations in there?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tommy, I am begining to think that most of these tutrials come from people who have managed to get lighting working and then assume they can teach it with poor explanations. Tommy if you have knowledge of lighting could you please look at my other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413164/opengl-es-2-0-lighting-view-and-world-space , i could do with a push in the right direction

Comment: That teapot looks odd. There's definitely something wrong, but it doesn't look like the result of properly applied per-vertex lighting. If you look at the two front most quads(?), the seams along their edges look brighter than the interior. I can't think of a reason why the interior of a polygon should be darker than all its edges if the color is properly interpolated.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just seeing mach bands? Like http://image.wikifoundry.com/image/1/6aca00oQDQX3y9pBVU4Qcg37385/GW400H400 — the diagonal on a square gradient isn't brighter but always appears to be. Here the edges act like the diagonal.

Comment: Possible that it's just a visible artifact. The laptop I'm on also has a poor screen, and it actually looks quite different depending on the angle I'm looking at the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Lighting calculations can be fairly expensive. Since there are a lot more fragments than vertices while rendering a typical model, it's generally more efficient to do the lighting calculations in the vertex shader, and interpolate the results across the fragments. Beyond the pure number of shader executions, performing typical lighting calculations in the fragment shader can also need more operations because interpolated normal need to be re-normalized, which requires relatively expensive `sqrt` operations.

The downside of per-vertex lighting is that it works poorly if the lighting values change quickly across a surface. This makes perfect sense, because the values are interpolated linearly across triangles. If the desired value does not change approximately linearly across the triangle, this will introduce artifacts.

The prototypical example are specular highlights. If you define a shiny material with relatively sharp/small specular highlights, you can easily see the brightness of the highlight changing while the object is animated. It also looks like the highlight seems to "wander" around on the object. For example, if you rotate a sphere with a specular highlight around its center, the highlight should stay exactly the same. But with per-vertex lighting, the brightness of the highlight will increase and decrease, and it will wobble slightly.

There's two main ways to avoid these effects, or at least reduce them to a level where they don't look disturbing anymore:

- Use per-fragment lighting.
- Use a finer tessellation for the geometry.

Which solution is better needs to be decided case by case. Of course using a finer tessellation adds overhead on the geometry processing side, while using per-fragment lighting adds overhead in the fragment shader.

Per-vertex lighting becomes even more problematic when you want to apply effects like bump mapping, where the lighting values change very quickly across the surface. In those cases, there's almost no way around using per-fragment lighting.

I have seen advice suggesting that GPUs were so fast now that per-vertex lighting should never be used anymore. I think that's a gross simplification. Even if you can get the desired performance with per-fragment lighting, most computers/devices these days are battery powered. To be power efficient, making your rendering as efficient as possible is as important as it ever was. And I believe that there are still use cases where per-vertex lighting is the most efficient approach.

Comment: I guess the trade off is also quite a bit different now than it was a decade or more ago when pixel shaders came in. If you're talking about devices like mobile phones then you're getting a huge number of pixels in a small area — 400, 500 dpi in some cases — and with geometry processing being ever speedier, polygons have become a lot smaller. Plus geometry shaders (albeit not yet on mobile) give you the option of factoring per-vertex lighting in as a consideration at runtime.